# How to modify list categories code?

Tags: categories

I'm using the following `wp_list_categories` code on category pages. If the current page is a parent category it displays all child categories of that category and if the current page is a child category it displays all the child categories of the parent category except the current category.

```
<?php if (is_category( )) {

    $cat = get_query_var('cat');
    $thiscat = get_category ($cat);
    $parent = $thiscat->parent;
    $catname = get_cat_name( $cat );

    if ($parent != '') {
    echo '<h2 class="widget-title"><span>Related Products</span></h2>';
    echo '<ul>';
    wp_list_categories( array(
        'title_li' => '',
        'child_of' => $parent,
        'exclude'  => $cat,
        'use_desc_for_title' => 0
    ) );
    echo '</ul>';
    }
    else {
    echo '<h2 class="widget-title"><span>' . $catname . '&nbsp;Products</span></h2>';
    echo '<ul>';
    wp_list_categories( array(
        'title_li' => '',
        'child_of' => $cat,
        'use_desc_for_title' => 0
        ) );
        echo '</ul>';
    }
} ?>
```

However, I now realize that I need to wrap each of the listed categories in a `<h3>` header element. Am I right in assuming that the only way to do this is to use `get_categories` and then output the required HTML using a `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 0):

I'm now using the following code which allows me to format the list as required:

```
<?php   if (is_category( )) {

        $thiscat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
        $catid = $thiscat->cat_ID;
        $parent = $thiscat->category_parent;

        if (!empty ($parent) ) {
        //child category pages

        $catlist = get_categories(
        array(
        'child_of' => $parent,
        'orderby' => 'id',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'exclude' => $catid,
        'hide_empty' => '0'
        ) );

        //widget title
        echo '<h2 class="widget-title"><span>Related Products</span></h2>';

        //categories list
        foreach ( $catlist as $category ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        echo '<li><h3 class="entry-title"><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->cat_ID ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . $category->cat_name . '</a></h3></li>';
        echo '</ul>';
        }
        }

        else {
        //parent category pages

        $catname = get_cat_name( $catid );

        $catlist = get_categories(
        array(
        'child_of' => $catid,
        'orderby' => 'id',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'hide_empty' => '0'
        ) );

        //widget title
        echo '<h2 class="widget-title"><span>' . $catname . '&nbsp;Products</span></h2>';

        foreach ( $catlist as $category ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        echo '<li><h3 class="entry-title"><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->cat_ID ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . $category->cat_name . '</a></h3></li>';
        echo '</ul>';
        }

        }

} ?>
```